# What steps are required for .ndo_start_xmit to work?

Tags: linux-device-driver, network-driver

I'm studying making an ethernet device driver in linux. Now, i confirmed that functions like probe, remove, .ndo_open, .ndo_stop work, but i couldn't see that .ndo_start_xmit works.
I want to know what kind of steps are required for .ndo_start_xmit to be called.